# Can't make comments on StackOverflow

Tags: support, comments

I can add an answer but I can't comment on any other answer. I havea reputation of over 10K and I have been able to comment for over a year, so wht is happening today to make the site decide I can't comment?

Comment: **Who are you?**

Comment: He's a smurf...

Comment: Is this a riddle?... I have legs, but never walk....

Comment: Who are you? Who? Who? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdYhR_WPfmY

Comment: Please link your accounts (see the 'accounts' tab in your SO user profile). You'll even get a 100 rep reward for doing so.

Comment: I'm just commenting to rub it in that I can comment and you can't.  HAHAHAHAHA!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Sometimes browsers / proxies inappropriately cache outdated versions of the files we serve and this causes problems.

Comment: I want to know how many times "clearing cache" has been the answer. Seems to be at least once every couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still shown as being logged in? Occasionally when I've suddenly lost the ability to do stuff, it's because the system has forgotten me for some reason - logging in clears everything up.

Comment: In soviet russia, stackoverflow forgets you!

Comment: Nobody forgets Jon Skeet. I think that happens because Jon Skeet forgot Stack Overflow.